# How to change positions of elements in two dimensional array in javascript and remove some elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got an array like this

```
var x = [[a, b, c],[d, e, f]];
```

and I need to get the following result

```
var x = [[b, a],[e, d]];
```

i.e. we need to change positions for two first elements and remove the last one?
Please, write function that can achieve this.

Comment: It is expected that you at least try to do your own work and then ask a question here about what you are having trouble with. This is NOT a code writing service.

Comment: Questions asking to write the code for you are not acceptable questions.

Comment: This looks like homework. Try and do it yourself, come back when you have actual question to ask

Comment: `function doYourOwnHomework() { window.open("https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays"); }`

Comment: You already have a solution cause you know the algorithm. So you just have to code it. If you don't know how to write specific operators and so on you have web resources like MDN.

Comment: to avoid downvotes for my answer and a mad teacher at your place....`function convert(arr) {
      var result = []
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        result.push([arr[i][1], arr[i][0]);
      }
    }
    convert([[a, b, c],[d, e, f]]);` .....

Comment: you have time until they will close this post xD

Comment: @Xander the function still has to be involked xD

Answer (score 2):

```
x = x.map(arr => arr.slice(0, 2).reverse());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to loop over each item, then [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) it to remove the last item, [reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) the array, then add it to the new array.

```js
var x = [['a', 'b', 'c'],['d', 'e', 'f']];

let result = x.reduce((arr, val) => {
    arr.push(val.slice(0,2).reverse())
    return arr
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: really with `reduce` instead of `map`?

Comment: I forget about map.

Answer (score 1):

You could map the result of a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and return a new array.

```js
var x = [['a', 'b', 'c'],['d', 'e', 'f']];

let result = x.map(([a, b]) => [b, a]);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: That is an awesome way to approach this!